# sql Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: sql

it had been a while since i used sql,

need a little push...

got 2 table, users and votes

```
users {id,email....}
votes {id,userid,date,vote}
```

the sql:

```
INSERT INTO votes_table (users_table.id , date,vote)
VALUES (    
            (SELECT users_table.id, users_table.email 
                FROM users_table
                WHERE users_table.email='lalala@lalall.com')
            ,datetime
            ,true
        )
```

the error

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner query is selecting 2 columns.  Change this to just return the id:

```
INSERT INTO votes_table (users_table.id , date,vote)
VALUES (    
            (SELECT users_table.id
                FROM users_table
                WHERE users_table.email='lalala@lalall.com')
            ,datetime
            ,true
        )
```

Comment: note that this code assumes only one user exists with the email specified.  if more than one user has that email, this will throw an error.  @rs. solution will not throw an error, but it will silently insert all users who have the same email address.  Neither issue matters if emails are unique-- just a reference for others who come across this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you are returning more number of columns in your sub-query, you can simply your query to this

```
INSERT INTO votes_table (users_table.id , date,vote)
SELECT users_table.id,datetime, true
                FROM users_table
                WHERE users_table.email='lalala@lalall.com'
```